# Картинка перекрывает текст

Tags: html, css

Когда открываю страничку в браузере фон перекрывает текст

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
  width: :100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("<img src="/images/intro.jpg" width="1917" height="1000">") no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="images/intro.jpg" width="1917" height="1000">
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Mogo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `background-image: url("<img src="/images/intro.jpg" width="1917" height="1000">") no-repeat center;` - что за фигня?

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url("<img src="/images/intro.jpg" width="1917" height="1000">")
```

Ты вставляешь HTML-код в ссылку на картинку.

```
background-image: url("./images/intro.jpg");
width: 1917px;
height: 1000px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Попробуй исправить на этот код.